# Dynamically creating variables in transmute

Tags: r, dplyr

As part of a simulation, I get an output that tells me which option was selected in every period (row) in each of the iterations (columns). My desired output is a new data frame that tells me the proportion of times each option was chosen in each of the periods (i.e. across iterations).

I have code that works for a particular number of options (see below for 5 options). However, the number of options is going to change across simulations, so I was wondering if there's a way to edit the part within transmute to create a variable for O1 through On, where `n = max(df)`.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
df <- sample(1:5, 50, replace=T) %>% matrix(ncol=5) %>% data.frame()

#>    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#> 1   2  4  3  3  2
#> 2   2  5  4  5  5
#> 3   3  2  3  2  4
#> 4   1  2  4  5  5
#> 5   3  4  3  4  4
#> 6   3  4  1  5  3
#> 7   5  2  4  1  4
#> 8   2  2  5  4  5
#> 9   3  2  3  5  2
#> 10  1  4  2  1  2

props <- df %>%
  transmute(period = 1:nrow(.),
  O1 = rowMeans(.==1),
  O2 = rowMeans(.==2),
  O3 = rowMeans(.==3),
  O4 = rowMeans(.==4),
  O5 = rowMeans(.==5))

#>    period  O1  O2  O3  O4  O5
#> 1       1 0.0 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.0
#> 2       2 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.2 0.6
#> 3       3 0.0 0.4 0.4 0.2 0.0
#> 4       4 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.2 0.4
#> 5       5 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6 0.0
#> 6       6 0.2 0.0 0.4 0.2 0.2
#> 7       7 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.4 0.2
#> 8       8 0.0 0.4 0.0 0.2 0.4
#> 9       9 0.0 0.4 0.4 0.0 0.2
#> 10     10 0.4 0.4 0.0 0.2 0.0
```

Comment: samll improvement: using `sapply` is faster and neater (avoid the `do.call(...)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do base `R`:

```
cbind(1:nrow(df),sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) rowMeans(df==i)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1  0.0  0.4  0.4  0.2  0.0
# [2,]    2  0.0  0.2  0.0  0.2  0.6
# [3,]    3  0.0  0.4  0.4  0.2  0.0
# [4,]    4  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.2  0.4
# [5,]    5  0.0  0.0  0.4  0.6  0.0
# [6,]    6  0.2  0.0  0.4  0.2  0.2
# [7,]    7  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.4  0.2
# [8,]    8  0.0  0.4  0.0  0.2  0.4
# [9,]    9  0.0  0.4  0.4  0.0  0.2
#[10,]   10  0.4  0.4  0.0  0.2  0.0
```